# Hibernate entity modelling for @ManyToMany joins

Tags: java, hibernate

[image]

I have 2 tables, View(viewId INTEGER) and Auth(login VARCHAR). I want to Create another table from joining View and Aut as follow using hibernate 4 and annotations.
Note I am adding another field visibile in that table.

```
@Entity
public class ViewAut {          

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="VIEW_VIEWID")
    private Rview view;             

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="AUT_USERID")  
    private Aut aut;                

    @Column                         
    private boolean visibile;       
    // Getter & setters
}
```

View object has a Set of ViewAut objects

```
@Entity                                          
public class View {
    // DONT KNOW HOW TO WRITE ANNOTATION FOR THIS SCENARIO
    private Set<ViewAut> authorizations;
```

Similary, Auth object has a Set of ViewAut objects

```
@Entity                                          
public class Aut {
    // DONT KNOW HOW TO WRITE ANNOTATION FOR THIS SCENARIO
    private Set<ViewAut> authorizations;
```

Can you please guide me on how to write those join in hibernate 4 annotations?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish can't be done with `Embeddable`. JPA defines `Embeddable` a class whose instances are stored as an intrinsic part of an owning entity and share the identity of the entity. Each of the persistent properties or fields of the embedded object is mapped to the database table for the entity, see [Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)

In this case you should model this `ViewAut` as another `Entity`, and using `OneToMany` to establish the relationship between them.

Comment: I have changed Embeddable to Entity, now how would you associate those 3 classes?

Comment: Using the `mappedBy` attribute of the `@OneToMany` Association. Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html). Also an entity need an Id so you should annotate in `ViewAut` both associations as part of the Composite Key. Check [`IdClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) for more information.